# Show that $f(k)$ is a closed set for all $f$.

Tags: functions, compactness

Here is part of a proof that I don't understand:

Let $X$ be a topological linear space and $K \subset X$ be non empty, compact and convex.

We have $\mathcal{F^*}$ is a commuting family of continuous transformations on $K$ that is closed under composition.

Then for all $f \in \mathcal{F^*}$ the set $f(K)$ is closed.

I don't see why this is true. At first I assumed it was due to the continuity of $f$ preserving the closedness of $K$, but we don't know that $K$ is closed, only that it is compact and convex, which as far as I know does not imlply that $K$ is closed in general.

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous function is always compact. Topological linear spaces (by definition, I think) are Hausdorff, and hence compact sets are closed.

Comment: @user744868 How would I show that the image of a compact set is closed under a continuous function?

Comment: Let $ \mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $f(K).$ Then show that $\{f^{-1}(U): U \in \mathcal{U} \}$ is an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact .... . Can you proceed ?

Comment: Following @Fred's comment You should be able to show that $f(K)$ is compact, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed) You find proofs that compact subsets of Hausdorff-spaces are closed.

Comment: Warning about french definition and english definition of compact (for frenchs all compact is Hausdorff)

Comment: @Piquito Good to point that out, it is even mentioned in the english [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Open_cover_definition)!